# Implement imagePicker in UIView class using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift4

I am trying to implement an imagePicker within my existing UIView class. It looks like you are only allowed to implement the UIImagePickerController in a ViewController class.

When implementing the imagePicker controller I am getting an "Use of unresolved identifier 'dismiss'" error before compiling.

I have explored several ways of evoking the imagePicker from the UIView class, but with no success.

One option that I explored was:
Declared a variable in the UIView class of type UIViewController(the parent UIViewController class from which the UIView class is populated). This resulted in initiating the UIViewController class again each time I want to add an image and this is not what I'm looking for

The reason why I'm doing it this way is that Ive implemented a Scroll View from the UIViewController class that uses the UIVIew class. These are both xib file implemnted classes.

Is there anyone that have tried something like this or have a better/working method of implementing what I need?

Please see sample of error and some code samples below:

[Error from UIView Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VotMo.png)

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    huntlogEditVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.imageView.image = selectedImage
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Please don't put code in images --- copy the code block into the question

Comment: Thanks. Updated my post.

Comment: How did huntlogEditVC get its value? Why not use it in the 2nd function

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly fine for me:

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let uierPickedInfo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as? UIImage {

        guard CIImage(image: userPickedInfo) != nil else {
            fatalError("Cannot convert")
        }
        imageView.image = userPickedInfo
    }
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: It is true that calling dismiss on the imagePicker will work, but this is not the correct way to do this.  It just so happens that iOS will forward this to the correct VC for you.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is probably to restructure this a little differently, but for something simple until you learn enough to do that.

The `UIImagePickerController` is a `UIViewController` and it has a property called `presentingViewController` which is the viewController that presented the picker, so ...

```
picker.presentingViewController.dismiss( ....
```

should work.

Alternatively -- how did you present the picker in the first place?  That `UIViewController` is the one you would normally call dismiss on.

Comment: Im implemented a scrollview on the UIViewController Class that populates the UIView class dynamically. My camera and gallery needs to be accessed from this UIView. Ive tried implementing your code, its not giving me a Fatal Error anymore, but its not opening up the camera either.

Am I taking a completely wrong approach?

Comment: dismiss closes the camera, so I don't really understand. It's not impossible to do what you want, but you need access to a VC in order to present and dismiss other VCs.

Answer (score 0):

create the imagePicker in the main View Controller and after selecting the image you can set the image in your coustom view, by creating a method to set the image in your coustom view and calling that method in your view controller with the selected image and this will eventually give you the functionality you need

```
class CoustomView : UIView{
@IBoutlet weak var ImageView1 : UIImageView
init(coder : NSCoder){ 
super.init(coder : coder)
}
func setImages(image : UIImage){
    
ImageView1.image = image

}

}


class mainController : UIViewController{
@IBoutlet weak var viewToBeSet : CoustomView!

viewDidLoad(){
// select the image using UIImagePicker and store in a variable then
// call the method of coustom view with stored image in argument to show 
// the image in your view 


viewToBeSet.setImage(image : selectedImage)
}

}
```